# How to create report with architecture layer?

Tags: asp.net

i work with Nhibernate's framework..
Would you give me advice, what I use to create a report for my web applications..??

Comment: NHibernate is not intended to be used as a reporting solution; it is an ORM.  Your reporting solution is unrelated to your use of NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ReportViewer control from Microsoft? I am guessing you are using Visual Web Developer?

[ReportViewer Controls (Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

In genereal you should try and add a little more information to your question. ;)